# this.userService.info$.subscribe() method not working in ngoninit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hello Guys i am trying to build create post section of a website in mean stack. Currently i am able to upload image title and tag from the form to backend and it is saving into mongodb also successfully. But when data is coming in form of res.send and when i am trying to get it to the home component file with the help of observable. I am unable to do this. Instead of giving complete flow of documents lets just pick the pain point. When i am trying to send the data from one component to other with help of observable i am unable to do this as the inner function is not at all responding also i am not even able to print hello in that subscribe function

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../shared/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  providers: [UserService]
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  tag: string;
  title: string;

  constructor(public userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("hello");
    this.userService.info$.subscribe(
      (res)=>{
        console.log("hello from subscribe")
        console.log(res)

        this.tag=res.tag;
        
        console.log(this.tag);
        
        this.title=res.title;
      },
      (err)=>{
        console.log(err)
      }
    )
  }

}
```

user.service.ts

```
receivedInfo = new Subject<any>();
  info$ = this.receivedInfo.asObservable();


  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  sendMessage(message: any){
    this.receivedInfo.next(message);
  }
```

uploadpost.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { UserService } from '../shared/user.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-uploadpost',
  templateUrl: './uploadpost.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./uploadpost.component.css'],
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class UploadpostComponent implements OnInit {

  images: any;
  showSuccessMessage: string;
  serverErrorMessages: string;

  constructor(public userService: UserService, public router: Router, public http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  selectImage(event: any) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    console.log(file)
    this.images = file;
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm){
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.images);
    formData.append('title', this.userService.selectedPost.title)
    formData.append('tag', this.userService.selectedPost.tag)
    formData.append('img', this.userService.selectedPost.img)
    console.log(formData)

    this.userService.upload(formData).subscribe(
      (res)=>{
        console.log("hello i am response from 3000")
        console.log(res)
        /* this.userService.infoReceived.emit(res); */
        this.userService.sendMessage(res)
        this.showSuccessMessage = 'Post Uploaded Successfully!';
        setTimeout(() => (this.showSuccessMessage = ''), 4000);
        this.resetForm(form)
        window.location.href = '/home';
      },
      (err)=>{
        this.serverErrorMessages = 'Something went wrong.Please contact admin.';
      }
    )
  }

  resetForm(form: NgForm) {
    this.userService.selectedPost = {
      title: '',
      tag: '',
      img: '',
    };
    form.resetForm();
    this.serverErrorMessages = '';
  }
}
```

cross-communicating-components are uploadpost and home in home component fir console.log("hello") is printing but not 2nd one this simply means it is not working and also in error block also nothing is printing

Comment: from where you are calling userService.sendMessage?

Comment: userService.sendMessage is called from user.service.ts file

Comment: It looks like your `home` component and your `uploadpost` component each have their own instance of `UserService` because you've included the service in their respective `providers` arrays. You can verify this by adding a `console.log` in the `UserService` constructor and you should see it log multiple times. You need to provide that service in a shared location so the `info$` Observable that `home` component subscribes to is the same Observable that `uploadpost` component is triggering an emit from.

Comment: Thank you, that helps. Can you please determine if I console.log the title or tag after the subscription statement in home component why I get undefined. I mean how can I use the title which I stored this.title = res.title after the subscription statement?

Comment: [Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nzlese?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) showing how providing `UserService` in a shared, parent location for the two components makes them share the same `userService.info$` Observable and therefore communicate effectively with each other (open the console to see the messages). Note that `UserService` is no longer in the `providers` array for each component but rather in the app.module's `providers` array, ensuring both components get the same instance of the service.

Comment: Yes, I have added UserService in app.module.ts and removed them from respective components. Now point is that in home component, in subscribe method, if I console.log the title, it's printed. But after the subscribe method if I console.log the title, it shows undefined.

Comment: When you say "after" the subscribe method, do you mean outside of the subscribe callback function? If so, `this.title` would be undefined there because it hasn't been set yet. When you call `this.userService.info$.subscribe()`, you're just registering the callback function—not executing it—then code execution continues to the next line, where `this.title` is still undefined. The subscribe callback function is called asynchronously sometime later, after the entire `ngOnInit` function has completed. So anything you need to do with `this.title` needs to be done inside the callback function.